# Spring @Transactional calling abstract superclass method throws org.hibernate.HibernateException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, transactional

I have read over 20 questions on stackoverflow related to this, but none of them worked.

Basically I have a service abstract superclass with 3 methods. Persist is like a template method, whereas save and update are overriden only when needed.

```
public abstract class BaseService<E> implements ServiceImpl{
    protected E save(E object, Class<E> returnedClass){//save object}
    protected E update(E object){//update object}

    public boolean persist(E object) {
        //validation rules

        if(shouldSave) {
            save(object);
        }else {
            update(object);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have this subclass

```
@Service
@Transactional
public CompanyService extends BaseService<Company> {
    @Autowired
    private CompanyRepository repository;

    public void testSaving(Company company) {
        repository.save(company);
    }

    @Override //from service impl
    public CommpanyRepositoy getRepository() {
        return repository;
    }
}
```

and this is my entry point

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/company")
public CompanyRestController {
    @Autowired
    private CompanyService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean save(@RequestBody Company company) {
        return service.persist(company);
    }
}
```

Now, the thing is, if I call for the `testSaving` method, everything goes right. BUT, when I call the `persist` method, it always give the error mentioned. I have tried lot's of things, like adding `@Transactional` to the `BaseService` superclass and even adding it to my repository doesn't work. Please, I need to fix this, its driving me crazy. Any advice?

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at br.com.jeffersontpadua.spring.generic.BaseRepository.getSession(BaseRepository.java:56)
    at br.com.jeffersontpadua.spring.generic.BaseRepository.save(BaseRepository.java:27)
    at br.com.jeffersontpadua.spring.service.BaseService.save(BaseService.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:723)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at br.com.jeffersontpadua.spring.service.CompanyService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a3329725.save(<generated>)
    at br.com.jeffersontpadua.spring.service.BaseService.persist(BaseService.java:34)
    at br.com.jeffersontpadua.spring.rest.CompanyRestController.save(CompanyRestController.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at br.com.jeffersontpadua.spring.filter.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: When you ask about an exception, **always** post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @JBNizet question updated

Answer (score 4):

This is intentional, see [SPR-7824](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7824).

You basically need to place the `@Transactional` annotation on the super-class rather than the subclass and that will cause all subclass methods to be transactional as well as those on the superclass.

If you cannot do that, override the methods in the subclass and delegate to the superclass.

Comment: I've added @Transactional to the superclass but even then it doesn't work. I thought about overriding methods, but I don't think it look nice. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: Hey man, for some unknown reason, overriding all methods involved in the transaction and calling for the superclass, makes it work, but that creates lots of issues. For example, now, anyone can override the default implementation of my template method. Do you have any thoughts on how to make it work without overriding?

Answer (score 2):

I finaly found a way to make this happen, so, for anyone who is still struggling to solve this, the trick is to add `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` to your superclass xD